# Returning All Values (Including Duplicates) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am unable to return all values, including duplicates, for the following query:

```
select all field1, count(field1)
from tablename
where
  field2 in (
    abc,
    abc,
    def,
    ghi,
    ghi
  )
group by field1
```

There are over 500 values for `field2` (which are zip codes), and I want to return each `field1` (area) which is assigned to each `field2` (zip code). If I run the above query, three areas are returned (for zip codes abc, def, ghi) instead of five. Below is a smaller version of the table I'm using; the actual table has ~500 rows.

I've a list of hundreds of zip codes (field2), which have all been assigned areas (field1). If, for example, I enter 400 non-distinct zip codes (field2), I would like to receive their 400 corresponding areas (field1). As of now, I'm only receiving the areas which correspond with the distinct zip codes.

**field2      field1**

**1**    66666     north
**2**    77777     south
**3**    88888     east
**4**    99999     west

I know there’s a simple solution to this, but I'm stumped. I’m using MS SQL Server; unfortunately, I do not have permission to create tables within the database.

Comment: You only have three unique values in the in.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. However, it is very likely that an example table and the corresponding output would illustrate your goal better than any explanation.

Comment: Your select is characters but you sample in numbers.  You have not even taken the effort to run a real query and show actual results. Down vote.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I knew how to write a "real query," I would have done so. Also, I have to partially disguise the results due to confidentiality. You were not born knowing this language...please be kind to those who seek your knowledge.

Comment: If you have confidential data then load some nonconfidential data to reproduce the problem.  Post the actual query and the actual output.

Answer (score 4):

**You have two issues.**

1 - You are using `GROUP BY` which by definition removes duplicate rows in the grouped field(s)

2 - You are using `IN`, which short circuits.  This means it ignores dupes and just returns a boolean.

You probably should try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE t_Field2 (field2 varchar(10))
INSERT INTO t_Field2
VALUES
('abc'....) <insert all your rows here>

SELECT Field1, COUNT(Field1)
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN t_Field2 t2
ON t2.field2 = t.field2
GROUP BY Field1
```

An `INNER JOIN` will definitely give you dupes in this scenario, which for some reason is what you want it sounds like.

The `GROUP BY` will still eliminate duplicate `Field1` values though.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2 
  FROM tablename
 WHERE field2 IN ( abc, def, ghi )
```

Also, your original query has an IN predicate that lists "abc" and "ghi" twice each.  The repetition does nothing; `field IN ( abc, abc )` is logically equivalent to `(field = abc OR field = abc)`

Comment: Hi. This query returned just three instances of each field2, as opposed to including the extra two duplicate instances. The original table has more than 500 field2 values, including duplicates. Thank you for the tip about in vs. =, though.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for, then. The query I showed you will give you all combinations of field1 and field2 values in your table, such that their field2 value is either abc, def or ghi. If you're seeing just one row for abc in the result set, and there is more than one row in your table with field2 = abc, it means then that both rows must have the same value for field1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm as stumped as the others as to quite what you're trying to do, but on the assumption that you're trying to provide a list of all the values (including duplicates) and the number of times each occurrs, it can be done with

```
SELECT a.field1, b.CountField
FROM   tablename a 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Field1, COUNT(*) AS CountField FROM TableName GROUP BY Field1) b
        ON a.Field1=b.Field1
```

But I can't for the life of me understand why you'd want that data over just

```
SELECT Field1, COUNT(*) AS CountField FROM TableName GROUP BY Field1
```

So, if you can clarify what you're trying to achieve, perhaps we can help more?